# How to navigate to the same URL but change (or add if missed) one of the query params

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is there a simple way to achieve that?

For example I want to set/change query parameter `qp` to the value `111`:

```
/p1/ ----> /p1/?qp=111
/p2/ ----> /p2/?qp=111
/p1/?ee=22 ----> /p1/?ee=22&qp=111
/p1/?ee=22&qp=222 ----> /p1/?ee=22&qp=111
```

etc

I tried to do `router.navigate([], { queryParams: { qp: '111' } });`
but it just replaces all query params with `qp=111`, if I set `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'` URL is not changing at all...

Comment: Well I knew that I can merge old params with new one myself but thought that there is a simple existing mechanism in router for such a common task. Sad. Thx to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to get the existing query params

```
const queryParams: Params = Object.assign({}, this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams);

// Do something with the params
queryParams['myParam'] = 'myNewValue';

this.router.navigate(['.'], { queryParams: queryParams });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge with the current query params.

To grab them, inject `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` as `routeSnap` and access the query params as

```
const oldParams = this.routeSnap.queryParams
```

You can also grab this object by injecting `ActivatedRoute` and accessing the query params with `this.route.snapshot.queryParams`.

In your examples, this would give you:

```
/p1/              ----> {}
/p2/              ----> {}
/p1/?ee=22        ----> {ee: 22}
/p1/?ee=22&qp=222 ----> {ee: 22, qp: 222}
```

Now you can navigate by merging with this object.

```
this.router.navigate([], {...oldParams, qp: 11})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your current `ActivatedRoute`

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.routeSnapshot = activatedRoute.snapshot['_routerState'].url;
  }

  this.router.navigate([this.routeSnapshot], {queryParams: { qp: '111' }});
```